# Date request param to Date object in Java

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, datetime

I receive in controller method following request:
`list?finish=2016-09-01T18:45:29.312Z&start=2016-09-01T18:45:29.312Z&userId=1`

In controller I have following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SimpleResponse<PagedResult<RecordApi>> list(PageableRequest pageRequest) {
    return ....;
}
```

And `PageableRequest` object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PageableRequest {

    private static final String DATETIME_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.SSSZ";

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, pattern = DATETIME_FORMAT)
    private Date start;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.NUMBER, pattern = DATETIME_FORMAT)
    private Date finish;
```

I tried different datetime formats, but it don't work:
`yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.SSSZ` or `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm.SSS'Z'` or `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm.SSSZ`

But I see each time `400 Bad Request`
How to solve this problem?

Comment: FYI, those date-time strings comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes can parse and generate such strings by default.

Comment: Isn't it because you got seconds in your timestamps? So HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Comment: There are two problems with your format: (1) You've missed the symbols for seconds, `s`. (2) You have used the wrong symbol for timezone offset. The symbol to parse the timezone offset is `X`. Thus, the correct format is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the method in a POST and and to mark your method argument with @RequestBody:

```
@PostMapping("/list")
public SimpleResponse<PagedResult<RecordApi>> list(@RequestBody PageableRequest pageRequest) {
    return ....;
}
```